# To add android in phonegap platform using cordova

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am trying to create an Android project with Cordova, however i am getting an ENOENT error although i followed the tutorial step by step very carefully, this is getting me angry. First this is the screenshot of the error: :[image]